# document.fonts.ready.then why considered Synchronous XMLHttpRequest

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, synchronous

When declaring font-face : browsers tends to wait to have text WITH this font to load the .ttf or .otf ...

I discovered this code

```
document.fonts.ready.then(function () { });
```

When I try

```
function myAajax () {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.open("POST", "ajax.php", true);
    ...
    xhr.send(params);
}

document.fonts.ready.then(function () { myAajax (); });
```

I get 
`[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest...` in chrome console log...

Will this eventually blocked ?

Comment: It’s not going to be possible for browsers to actually remove sync XHR any time soon. Unfortunately there’s still too much content on the web that’s (mis)using it. See https://github.com/whatwg/xhr/issues/20. But that doesn’t make it good. You still shouldn’t use it. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wer/2011/08/03/why-you-should-use-xmlhttprequest-asynchronously/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests and the many other places where it’s been explained why sync XHR is bad and what you should use instead.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I found is to make a div with display hidden

```
<div id="ajaxContent" style="display:none;"></div>
```

then call my ajax, and when fonts ready, show the div...

```
myAajax ();
document.fonts.ready.then(function () {$("#ajaxContent").show(); });
```